# Java Method step into if-Clause even though it's false

Tags: java, if-statement, arraylist

I'm using a synchronized Method which is called 60x per second. The method checks whether a ArrayList is empty or not. And even if it's empty, it steps into the if-clause...

```
public synchronized void removeGameObjectsFromList()
{
    if (!GAMEOBJECTSTOREMOVE.isEmpty())
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < GAMEOBJECTSTOREMOVE.size(); i++)
        {
            GameObject obj = GAMEOBJECTSTOREMOVE.get(i);
            getRegionNodes().getChildren().remove(obj.getCurrentImageView());
            GAMEOBJECTS.remove(obj.getNAME());             
        }
        GAMEOBJECTSTOREMOVE.clear();
        System.out.println("Finished");
    }
    System.out.println(GAMEOBJECTSTOREMOVE.isEmpty());
}
```

The Output looks like:

```
{true
Finished
true
Finished
true
true
Finished
true
true
Finished
true}
```

Why can it step into if() whether its empty?

The method is called in a "BulletManager" which updates all "living" Bullets in my view:

```
AnimationTimer timer = new AnimationTimer()
    {
        @Override
        public void handle(long now)
        {
            if (!(BULLETS.isEmpty()))
            {
                for (int i = 0; i < BULLETS.size(); i++)
                {
                    Bullet currentBullet = BULLETS.get(i);
                    if (currentBullet.getDistance() > 0)
                    {
                            currentBullet.move(currentBullet.getANGLE());
                            currentBullet.getCurrentImageView().setTranslateX(currentBullet.getCoordinate().getX());
                            currentBullet.getCurrentImageView().setTranslateY(currentBullet.getCoordinate().getY());
                        currentBullet.decrementDistance();
                    } else
                    {
                        GAMEMANAGER.addGameObjectToBeRemoved(currentBullet);

                    }
                }

            }
        }
    };
    timer.start();
```

Comment: A lot of reasons why it could happen...

Comment: "Why can this happen?" It cannot. Have you tried debugging your code? Also, you should print `GAMEOBJECTSTOREMOVE.isEmpty()` at the star tof the method.

Comment: Please provide a [mcve].

Comment: The empty check is pointless because of the for loop that already checks the size

Comment: The list is not empty. Is the code that puts things into the ArrayList also synchronized on the same object?

Comment: Yes but I can't debug to the Point where this happens because the method is called 60x per second and the "true finished" part starts after creating and removing a bullet

Comment: What puts the things in the shouty GAMEOBJECTSTOREMOVE?

Comment: @Myrtium move the `System.out.println(...)` to the start of the method and rerun the program. I am willing to bet some money that the output will change.

Comment: Read on thread safety and memory models. This is, for sure, a problem with caching and threads not seeing the actual value.

Comment: Yes all methods for this ArrayLists are synchronized. @Turing85 k I Moved the System.out... to the Top and it's actually false now... But Why? I clear() the whole ArrayList

Comment: @Myrtium Yes. You clear the `ArrayList` in the last statement within the `if (...)`. Therefore it must be empty after the `if`...

Comment: Synchronized does not mean thread-safe. There's more to thread-safety than meets the eye. Your code is in no way atomic. It has lot of race conditions happening. I'd suggest you read on thread safety before blaming java's `ArrayList`.

Comment: @Tom Mac `public synchronized void addGameObjectToBeRemoved(GameObject obj)
    {
        GAMEOBJECTSTOREMOVE.add(obj);
    }`
For example: the method is called after a Bullet has reached the maximal distance.

Comment: @sturcotte06 Thank you for your answer. This is my first "big project" I have to work on... I've read a bit about race conditions before but I don't know what I have to change...

Answer (score 1):

This is nothing to do with thread safety, as suggested in the comments above. Look at this reduced code:

```
if (!GAMEOBJECTSTOREMOVE.isEmpty())
{
    /* ... */
    GAMEOBJECTSTOREMOVE.clear();
    System.out.println("Finished");
}
System.out.println(GAMEOBJECTSTOREMOVE.isEmpty());
```

So, if it's not empty, you clear its contents, making it empty, then you print that it's empty.

And if it's already empty, you just print that it's empty.

Hence, you will always print `true` on the second `System.out.println`, which occurs after the `clear`.

Comment: Okey I tried it but same output: (true, Finished, true, Finished)

Comment: You tried... what? I've not suggested any change to the code here. I'm merely showing what happens to the contents of `GAMEOBJECTSTOREMOVE`; the loop is irrelevant because it doesn't mutate it.

Comment: Oh sorry... I thought you suggested your reduced code for any reasons... Too maybe see a sneaky misstake

Comment: There's nothing sneaky here. You're clearing a collection, and then wondering why it's showing as being empty.

Comment: No... I'm clearing the ArrayList and after clearing it shloudnt step into the if() clause anymore because it obviously should be empty but it isnt.

Answer (score -1):

Okey I found a solution... I'm just dumb ... sooo dumb... If I create a Bullet the Object is added to the GameManager "GAMEOBJECTLIST" and to the BulletManager "BULLETLIST"... after reaching the maximal distance of the bullet, its removed from the GameManager list, but not from the BulletManager List... this was the hole problem... Now everything works fine... I'm stupid